# ApolloClient Caching does not store every item

Tags: react-native, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have a problem with ApolloClient Caching. There are a few items that are not stored in the cache.

Env: React Native

Packages:

- @apollo/client
- @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
- apollo3-cache-persist

Result (without Caching):

```js
contentElements: [{
  __typename: "My_Stage",
  cta: {label: "Test", link: "mylink", __typename: "CTA"},
  id: "0123234234234234234234",
}]
```

Result (with Caching: strategy: cache-first)

```js
contentElements: [{
  __typename: "My_Stage",
}]
```

I dont think this is a problem with normalization because the element has an `id` and `__typename`.
I have also tried to disable normalization with `keyFields: false` for `Stage` but this did not work.

Let me know if i did not deliver enough information. Thank you for your help!